# Detecting the termination of multiple child processes

Tags: c, process

I have to write code for creating multiple child processes using a parent.
Parent process should be sleeping until it creates the number of processes.
Child processes send SIGCHLD signal to parent process to interrupt from the sleep and force the parent to call wait for the Collection of status of terminated child processes.

I have write following code on UBUNTU:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* needed to define exit() */
#include <unistd.h> /* needed for fork() and getpid() */
#include <signal.h> /* needed for signal */
#include <stdio.h>  /* needed for printf() */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
void catch(int);    /* signal handler */
void child(int);    /* the child calls this */
void parent(int pid);   /* the parent calls this */
int pid;        /* process ID */
int i;          /* Number of processes*/

signal(SIGCHLD, catch); /* detect child termination */

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    pid = fork();   /* create child process*/
    switch (pid) 
    {
    case -1:    /* something went wrong */
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    case 0:     /* a fork returns 0 to the child */
        child(i+1);
        break;
    default:    /* a fork returns a pid to the parent */
        //parent(pid);
        break;
    }
}
exit(0);
}

void child(int id)
{
    printf("\tchild%d: I'm the child\n",id);
    sleep(10);      /* do nothing for 3 seconds */
    printf("\tchild: I'm exiting\n");
    exit(id);       /* exit with a return code of 123 */
}

void parent(int pid)
{
    printf("parent: I'm the parent\n");
    sleep(15);      /* do nothing for five seconds */
    printf("parent: exiting\n");
}

void catch(int snum)
{
    int pid;
    int status;

    pid = wait(&status);
    printf("parent: child process exited with value %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
    /* WEXITSTATUS(status):
     * Since only the last 8 bits are available 
     * it will be logical to mask the upper bit by   
     * doing a bitwise and operation with 255. 
     * A system defined macro does this for us. 
     */
}
```

And I am getting output like this:

```
parent: I'm the parent
    child1: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 1
parent: exiting
parent: I'm the parent
    child2: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 2
parent: exiting
parent: I'm the parent
    child3: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 3
parent: exiting
parent: I'm the parent
    child4: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 4
parent: exiting
parent: I'm the parent
    child5: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 5
parent: exiting
```

whereas I want output like this:

```
parent: I'm the parent
    child1: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 1
    child2: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 2
    child3: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 3
    child4: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 4
    child5: I'm the child
    child: I'm exiting
parent: child process exited with value 5
parent: exiting
```

what changes I should make in my code...?
please help..!!!

Comment: To me this looks as if output and source do not match.

Comment: i have given here expected output and the output i m getting.
The first one is what i am getting, and the other one is what i expect.

Comment: In the source code you you the one call to `parent()` is commented out.

Comment: ignore that comments

Comment: "**you you*" should read "you show" or wtf ... sry ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the code, the main function exits after starting the children. You need to add code that waits until all children have exited, means the `SIGCHLD` signal was caught for each exit of your child.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `parent: I'm the parent` and `parent: exiting` within the loop. If you want them to be printed only once, move them out of the loop.

You may also want to look into using the `wait` or `waitpid` functions for waiting for child process termination instead of using a signal handler and `sleep`.